# Is there a name for this construction in category theory?

Tags: category-theory

Let $T : \mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal B$ be a functor. Let $\mathcal C$ be the category whose objects are the objects of $\mathcal A$ and whose morphisms are given as $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(A,B) = \text{Hom}_{\mathcal B}(TA,TB)$. Composition is defined using composition in $\mathcal B$.

Is there a neater way to construct the category $\mathcal C$? I'm thinking maybe of using comma categories or other more general notions but can't actually come up with a category isomorphic to $\mathcal C$ using these methods.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Isn't this just the full subcategory of $\mathcal{B}$ generated by the image of $T$?

Comment: No, since if $\mathcal A$ is the category with two objects $\circ, *$ and only identity morphisms and $T$ is a functor so that $T \circ = T *$, the full subcategory generated by the image of $T$ will have one object but $\mathcal C$ will have two objects. I.e they aren't isomorphic, I'm not sure if these categories are equivalent or not though. I would say probably not for general $\mathcal B$.

Comment: If $\mathcal B $ is the category with one object and a single nontrivial morphism $f$ so that $f \circ f = f$ and $\mathcal A$ is as before then $\mathcal C$ and the category you proposed, call it $\mathcal D$, are not even equivalent. @NoahSchweber

Comment: @NoelLundström I don't follow your counterexample. I think the functor induced by the object map of $T$ from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$ (Noah Schweber's category) is fully faithful by construction of $\mathcal{C}$, and essentially surjective by definition of $\mathcal{D}$, and therefore an equivalence of categories.

Comment: Yes... that makes sense... but I also don't see where my own argument fails, if $F:\mathcal D \rightarrow \mathcal C$ is any functor it can't be essentially surjective since there are no nontrivial maps in $\mathcal C$ which are isomorphisms i.e $*$ and $\circ$ are not isomorphic in $\mathcal C$. Hence $F$ can't be an equivalence. @jgon

Comment: @NoelLundström Even though $*$ and $\circ$ are not isomorphic in $\mathcal{A}$, they become isomorphic in $\mathcal{C}$, since $T$ is forced to send both $*$ and $\circ$ to the single object of $\mathcal{B}$, so $T*=T\circ$, and $\mathcal{C}(*,\circ) = \mathcal{B}(T*,T\circ) = \{f,1\}$ contains the identity on the single object of $\mathcal{B}$, which becomes the isomorphism between the two in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Oh, that's very sneaky. I wouldn't have spotted that myself. I think I see where to go from here. Thanks! @jgon